# use full width responsive slider in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, branding

hi I want to use this slider in my sharepoint 2013 but I donot know how could I use it?
 http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Full-Width-Responsive-Carousel-with-jQuery-Bootstrap.html

Comment: Look here is a cool Tesla X, can anybody tell me how I can build one myself? StackOverflow is about helping you with coding problems, we are not here to do your job. If you don't have the skills yet to do your job then do what all of us did. We roamed the internet for weeks, reading blogs, trying pieces of code, slowly getting comfortable with coding [in SharePoint]

Comment: thank you but as I know  I cannot use js in content editor webpart

Comment: **So you are now saying you have a hammer put it can't be used with nails...** Then you have to learn the CEWP first..

Answer (score 1):

> **Disclaimer**: *I see an influx of Asian accounts, asking questions as if they started with SharePoint yesterday, and think StackOverflow is a free training site.
>
>   It is not!
>
>   We are here to help you when you tried (very) hard to solve you coding problem yourself,
>
>   We are **not** here to do your job.*

---

Start by learning to use the CEWP (Content Editor WebPart)

https://www.google.nl/search?q=youtube+cewp

Comment: hi used script editor and copy the code I it and copy .js and .jsmin in site assets and change the adress to it but the pictures didnot move should I change all .js urls ?

Comment: Your next lesson then is to learn and use the F12 developers console, and see what is going wrong. Unless you give me your admin password, then I can check what is going wrong.